# Bijection between (n choose k) and bitstrings of length n with k bits set

Tags: algorithm, bitstring, hammingweight, bijection

While I know how to generate all (`n` choose `k`) bitstrings of size `n` with exactly `k` bits set to one, I'm struggling finding a bijection, that gets as input a number `i` between `1` and (`n` choose `k`) and outputs the `i`-th vector of that kind in an arbitrary ordering.

Obviously, one could simply enumerate all of that vectors in a list and then output the `i`-th entry of the list, but unfortunately that approach has to high memory requirements for my setting.

Edit: also it should be an efficient computation, computing the list of all vectors for each call to the bijection is also not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straightforward way:

If **i < (n-1 choose k)**, then the leftmost bit is **0** and **i** determines the remainder of the bits recursively.  Otherwise, the leftmost bit is **1**, and **i - (n-1 choose k)** determines the remainder of the bits recursively. In the second case there are at most **(n-1 choose k-1)** possible values of **i - (n-1 choose k)**.